# Internet Explorer 8 - TLS Fatal Error Close Notify - Oracle HTTP - Server Apache 2.2.22.0

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, oracle, internet-explorer

I applied the POODLE fix for Apache via `SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3` in the `ssl.conf` file for our Apache server but am having issues with the **CAC Client authentication** via `SSLVerifyClient require`.

I have confirmed if I set `SSLVerifyClient none` our web application can be accessed via HTTPS and uses the correct protocol of TLSv1 but once I set `SSLVerifyClient require` (which is needed because our Web Application is CAC enabled) I get a `page cannot be displayed` in IE (IE has SSLv2 and SSLv3 disabled but TLS1.0-3 enabled).

The client is Windows 7 32 bit with IE 8. Server is Windows 2003 SP2.

I have done a packet capture between the client and server. The first client hello is for TLSv1.2 a Fatal Error Close Notify is then sent.

Since my server does not support TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2 then a Client Hello is sent for TLSv1. The process goes all the way up to Client Certificate request Server Hello Done, then another Fatal Error Close Notify is sent by the client..

Screen Cap here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy8J6.jpg
[image]

Here are the Full TCP streams:

The First stream a client hello is sent and tries to negotiate TLSv1.2 the server rejects as it doesn't support and sends a close notify. The Second stream sends a client hello over TLSv1.0 is send etc.. But this is from one single connection to the web server..

1st stream: [image: i.imgur.com/pmiXn9t.jpg]

2nd stream: [image: i.imgur.com/NIh1lsZ.jpg]

The connection is at TLSv1 as I have verified from https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/. The server even agrees on a TLS cipher..

Chrome does work fine even with SSLv2 and SSLv3 disabled via `chrome.exe --ssl-version-min=tls1`

Also this version of Apache uses `mod_ossl`

> The `mod_ossl` module enables strong cryptography for Oracle HTTP
> Server. This Oracle module is a plug-in to Oracle HTTP Server that
> enables the server to use SSL. It is very similar to the OpenSSL
> module, `mod_ssl`. The `mod_ossl` module is based on the Oracle
> implementation of SSL, which supports SSL version 3 and TLS version 1,
> and is based on Certicom and RSA Security technology.

I don't know how to upgrade this to support TLS v1.1 and TLS v1.2 as I am on the latest OHS 11g release from Oracle and this is a custom module made by Oracle..

UPDATE:

I have enabled debug log level on the OHS Apache logs. I now receive the following errors when using IE to try an access the web application:

```
[Mon Nov 10 08:16:05 2014] [error] [client X.X.X.X] OHS:2079 nzos handshake error, nzos_Handshake returned 28858(server X.X.X.X:443, client X.X.X.X)
[Mon Nov 10 08:16:05 2014] [error] OHS:2171 NZ Library Error: SSL protocol error [Hint: the client probably speaks HTTPS over HTTP protocol]
[Mon Nov 10 08:16:05 2014] [info] [client X.X.X.X] OHS:2073 Connection to child 107 closed with standard shutdown(server X.X.X.X:443, client X.X.X.X)
[Mon Nov 10 08:16:05 2014] [info] [client X.X.X.X] Connection to child 107 established (server X.X.X.X:443)
[Mon Nov 10 08:16:06 2014] [info] [client X.X.X.X] OHS:2079 nzos handshake error, nzos_Handshake returned 28864(server X.X.X.X:443, client X.X.X.X)
[Mon Nov 10 08:16:06 2014] [info] OHS:2171 NZ Library Error: SSL IO error [Hint: the client stop the connection unexpectedly]
[Mon Nov 10 08:16:06 2014] [info] [client X.X.X.X] OHS:2073 Connection to child 107 closed with standard shutdown(server X.X.X.X:443, client X.X.X.X)
```

Anyone know how to fix this on Oracle HTTP Server (OHS) Apache 2.2.22.0??

Here is a snippet of my `ssl.conf` file:

```
###################################################################
# Oracle HTTP Server mod_ossl configuration file: ssl.conf        #
###################################################################


# OHS Listen Port
Listen 443

<IfModule ossl_module>
##
##  SSL Global Context
##
##  All SSL configuration in this context applies both to
##  the main server and all SSL-enabled virtual hosts.
##

#
#   Some MIME-types for downloading Certificates and CRLs
    AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
    AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

#   Pass Phrase Dialog:
#   Configure the pass phrase gathering process.
#   The filtering dialog program (`builtin' is a internal
#   terminal dialog) has to provide the pass phrase on stdout.
    SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

#   Inter-Process Session Cache:
#   Configure the SSL Session Cache: First the mechanism 
#   to use and second the expiring timeout (in seconds).
    SSLSessionCache "shmcb:${ORACLE_INSTANCE}/diagnostics/logs/${COMPONENT_TYPE}/${COMPONENT_NAME}/ssl_scache(512000)"
    SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

#   Semaphore:
#   Configure the path to the mutual exclusion semaphore the
#   SSL engine uses internally for inter-process synchronization. 
    <IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
      SSLMutex "none"
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
      SSLMutex pthread
    </IfModule>

##
## SSL Virtual Host Context
##
<VirtualHost *:443>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "${ORACLE_INSTANCE}/config/${COMPONENT_TYPE}/${COMPONENT_NAME}/htdocs/asset"
    DirectoryIndex remagnum.html
    ServerName TTSDS09083.TIMPO.OSD.MIL
#    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com

  <IfModule ossl_module>

   #  SSL Engine Switch:
   #  Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
   SSLEngine on

   #  SSL Cipher Suite:
   #  List the ciphers that the client is permitted to negotiate.
   #SSLCipherSuite SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

   SSLCipherSuite ALL:+HIGH:-MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-SSLv3

   SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3


   #  Client Authentication (Type):
   #  Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
   #  none, optional and require.
   #SSLVerifyClient none
   SSLVerifyClient require

   # SSL Certificate Revocation List Check
   # Valid values are On and Off
   SSLCRLCheck Off

   #Path to the wallet
   SSLWallet "${ORACLE_INSTANCE}/config/${COMPONENT_TYPE}/${COMPONENT_NAME}/keystores/default"

   <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData

   </FilesMatch>

   <Directory "${ORACLE_INSTANCE}/config/${COMPONENT_TYPE}/${COMPONENT_NAME}/cgi-bin">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData

   </Directory>

  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Which versions of Internet Explorer and Windows?

Comment: Internet Explorer 8 and Windows Server 2003 R2.. will edit OG post

Comment: It works if i turn on SSLv3 on Internet Explorer.. The client is Windows 7 32 bit. Server is Windows 2003 SP2

Answer (score 3):

> SSLCipherSuite ALL:+HIGH:-MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-SSLv3

Since you disable all SSL 3.0 ciphers and since TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 just use the SSL 3.0 ciphers and since IE 8 does not support TLS 1.2 there will be no shared ciphers. You will probably find some error messages about this in your log files.

Note, that the POODLE attack is a design flaw in the SSL 3.0 protocol, not in the SSL 3.0 ciphers. Thus you should only disable the protocol, not the ciphers.

Also, your current cipher suite includes very dangerous ciphers, because it includes ADH ciphers which don't require any form of identification of the server. With such ciphers man-in-the-middle attacks are possible.

Edit: in your comment you mention that the client is using Windows 7. Windows 7 should support TLS 1.2 but since the client obviously did not do much updates on the system (otherwise there would be no IE 8 in use) it might be that there are problems with IE 8 and TLS 1.2.

Comment: I doubt that Apache in Windows uses Schannel. It probably uses OpenSSL, but the version is unknown too me.

Comment: Even if i set it to "SSLCipherSuite ALL" I still have the same exact issue. The issue isnt the cipher since it agrees on a cipher just fine..

Comment: Could you please provide the packet capture (at cloudshark.org). It looks very strange for me but sometimes the devil lurks in the details  . And please have a look at the error log of the server.

Comment: I attached a screen shot in my original post.

Comment: Also this version of Apache uses mod_ossl "The mod_ossl module enables strong cryptography for Oracle HTTP Server. This Oracle module is a plug-in to Oracle HTTP Server that enables the server to use SSL. It is very similar to the OpenSSL module, mod_ssl. The mod_ossl module is based on the Oracle implementation of SSL, which supports SSL version 3 and TLS version 1, and is based on Certicom and RSA Security technology." I dont know how to upgrade this to support TLS v1.1 and TLS v1.2 as I am on the latest 11g release from oracle and this is a custom module made by oracle..

Comment: Sorry, but in this dump are multiple (overlapping?) connections are merged together, because no ClientHello follows a close alert. This way the dump is not really helpful. And again - did you ever look into the log files of the server for hints whats going on?

Comment: I have also verified this does not work on IE 10 on a Windows 8 box with SSLv2 and SSLv3 disabled and TLSv1.0-3 enabled

Comment: No this is one session.. up to NO 29 is where the browser asks me for my certificate (CAC) and when i press ok is when i receive the rest of the packets and a page cannot be displayed in IE.. I can take the TLS filter off in wireshark if that helps.. but it just makes it longer. I cannot not find where the SSL specific logs are located for Oracle HTTP Server. All ican see is the OHS log where it tells me if the syntax is right in the ssl.conf and start and stop process logging

Comment: I don't think there are SSL specific logs, just use the default error log. And I asked to have a single connection, that is a single TCP connection. Obviously there a multiple overlapping TCP connections inside your dump which might be still part of the same page, but nevertheless they are more than one TCP connection. Please restrict with "tcp.stream eq 1" etc to have only a single failed connection.

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e10144/man_logs.htm where to find the log files.

Comment: yeah ive looked at those but nothing about ssl errors.. maybe if i set the logging level to debug. I will try that. So there are 2 streams.. the first stream a client hello is sent and tries to negotiate TLSv1.2 the server rejects as it doesnt support and sends a close notify. The second stream sends a client hello over TLSv1.0 is send etc.. But this is from one single connection to the web server.. 1st stream: http://i.imgur.com/pmiXn9t.jpg 2nd stream: http://i.imgur.com/NIh1lsZ.jpg

Comment: With connection a mean TCP connection and these are obviously two, both starting with SYN handshake and ending with FIN handshake and having different source ports. Anyway: the first one shows that the server just closes if it gets a TLS1.2 handshake. The seconds shows that the client (browser) closes if it receives the reply from the server with the CertificateRequest. The only explanation I have here is that the client has no client certificate configured which matches the servers request. So it would be good to compare the certificate the client has to what the server wants.

Comment: Just a guess because I've seen exactly this before: Client has only certificate signed with MD5 but server supports only other hash algorithms for signature.

Comment: but then the question is why does my client certificate work with chrome? I can attach a packet dump from a successful chrome session if it helps.

Comment: and yes it is technically two connections but IE does the auto reconnect to TLSv1. I literally hit enter in the address bar in IE and this is how the dump came out..

Comment: Client Cert is signed with Sha1RSA.. Keep in mind this is working fine on SSLv3 and works fine as it is now on Chrome..

Comment: This gets really strange. Right now I assume that IE has the problems to handle the CertificateRequest. Please try to leave SSL 3.0 enabled on the client site and see if this works. It still should use TLSv1 because this is the best version shared with the server.

Comment: So I have looked at the Oracle Wallet (Which contains the server certificate and trusted certificates) and it is missing the trusted certificate used by my CAC. I have tried adding this to the wallet but I cannot delete the old ones as it says i have to remove the user certificate. I am trying to figure out how to resign the certificate with the new CA.. What should i use to sign this "keytool" "openssl"?

Comment: I have no idea how Oracle Wallet works but I'm sure that you find documentation about it online, see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asowalet.htm#i1009041